# Fix grub2 without breaking the encrypted partition

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, upgrade, boot-repair

I did an `update-grub` and broke the grub somehow!
Now, there a couple of ways to fix it, but I faced different problems. My Ubuntu version was `19.04`. I made a live USB using the `19.10` version available.

I managed to access my encrypted partition and followed the steps in [This Answer](https://superuser.com/questions/376470/how-to-reinstall-grub2-efi).

Here is the output of `fdisk`:

```
/dev/nvme0n1p1    2048    1050623    1048576   512M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2 1050624    2549759    1499136   732M Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p3 2549760 2000408575 1997858816 952.7G Linux filesystem
```

This is the result of the final `efibootmgr -v` command:

```
root@ubuntu:/# efibootmgr -v
BootCurrent: 000A
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0004,0003,0000,0002,0006,0007,0008,0009,000A
Boot0000* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,7d1e35c6-33b5-48b3-a7d2-484e6f100a4a,0x800,0x100000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)
Boot0001* Linux HD(3,GPT,39693e09-5016-4b13-a215-f297365e5d57,0x26e800,0x7714e800)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\grub.efi)
Boot0002* UEFI: KXG60ZNV1T02 NVMe TOSHIBA 1024GB, Partition 1   HD(1,GPT,7d1e35c6-33b5-48b3-a7d2-484e6f100a4a,0x800,0x100000)/File(\EFI\boot\bootx64.efi)..BO
Boot0003* Linux HD(1,GPT,7d1e35c6-33b5-48b3-a7d2-484e6f100a4a,0x800,0x100000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\grub.efi)
Boot0004* Linux HD(1,GPT,7d1e35c6-33b5-48b3-a7d2-484e6f100a4a,0x800,0x100000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\grub.efi)
Boot0006* Diskette Drive    BBS(Floppy,Diskette Drive,0x0)..BO
Boot0007* USB Storage Device    BBS(USB,Sony Storage Media 0100,0x0)..BO
Boot0008* CD/DVD/CD-RW Drive    BBS(CDROM,CD/DVD/CD-RW Drive,0x0)..BO
Boot0009* Onboard NIC   BBS(Network,Onboard NIC,0x0)..BO
Boot000A* UEFI: Sony Storage Media 0100, Partition 1    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x14,0x0)/USB(1,0)/HD(1,MBR,0xb6e913b,0x800,0xf16000)..BO
```

I know some of the entries are wrong or redundant, but don't know what to do from here. How do I check?